# ember-data working as expected only if app entry point access data

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have a strange problem with ember-data, on one entry point it loads the data from the server (I enabled logging on the server to see what's happening), but on a different entry point and then change route to the same state as the first option, ember-data doesn't access the server at all.

I simply can't understand why this is happening.

in my app, if I point the browser to /posts, data is loaded from the server and everything is ok.  but if I point to /settings, and then follow a link to change routes to posts.index, ember-data doesn't access the server.

also, if my entry point is /posts/new and I try to create a new post I get an error:
    `http://localhost:3000/api/unknown%20mixin)s 404 (Not Found)`

what can be the problem ?

EDIT: If I load data by invoking `findAll()` in the controller's init function, the data is loaded when the controller is first instantiated and everything is fine.. but I still don't understand this weird behavior. is it a bug ?

EDIT2: I created a github project to show this issue - https://github.com/bsphere/ember-data-test

```
App.Router = Ember.Router.extend({
enableLogging:  true,
root: Ember.Route.extend({
    showposts: Ember.Route.transitionTo('posts.index'),
    showSettings: Ember.Route.transitionTo('settings.index'),

    index: Ember.Route.extend({
        route: '/',
        connectOutlets: function(router) {
            router.transitionTo('posts.index');
        }
    }),
    settings: Ember.Route.extend({
        route: '/settings',
        connectOutlets: function(router) {
            router.get('applicationController').connectOutlet('navigation', 'navigation');
        },
        index: Ember.Route.extend({
            route: '/',
            connectOutlets: function(router) {
                router.get('applicationController').connectOutlet('content', 'settings');
                router.set('navigationController.selected', 'settings');
            }
        })
    }),
    posts: Ember.Route.extend({
        newpost: Ember.Route.transitionTo('root.posts.new'),
        editpost: Ember.Route.transitionTo('root.posts.edit'),

        route: '/posts',
        connectOutlets: function(router) {
            router.get('applicationController').connectOutlet('navigation', 'navigation');
        },
        index: Ember.Route.extend({
            route: '/',
            connectOutlets: function(router) {
                router.set('navigationController.selected', 'posts');
                router.get('applicationController').connectOutlet('content', 'posts',
                    App.store.findAll(App.Post));
            }
        }),
        new: Ember.Route.extend({
            route: '/new',
            connectOutlets: function(router) {
                router.set('navigationController.selected', '');
                router.get('applicationController').connectOutlet('content', 'post',
                    App.store.createRecord(App.Post));
                router.set('postController.isEditing', false);
            },
            cancel: function(router) {
                router.transitionTo('index');
            },
            didCreate: function(router) {
                router.transitionTo('index');
            }
        }),
        edit: Ember.Route.extend({
            route: '/:id/edit',
            connectOutlets: function(router, post) {
                router.set('navigationController.selected', '');
                router.get('applicationController').connectOutlet('content', 'post',
                    App.store.find(App.Post, post.get('id')));
                router.set('postController.isEditing', true);
            },
            deserialize: function(router, context) {
                return App.store.find(App.Post, context.id)
            },
            serialize: function(router, post) {
                return {
                    id: post.get('id')
                }
            },
            cancel: function(router) {
                router.transitionTo('index');
            },
            didUpdate: function(router, post) {
                router.transitionTo('index');
            }
        })
    })
})
});
```

Comment: This is the intended behavior. Once a find is run the results are cached locally and running the find again will not trigger any adapter methods.

Comment: I know that, and its not the problem I'm describing.
If I point my browser to /settings, and then follow a link to /posts ember-data isn't getting any resources from nowhere. another test - if i point to /posts/new and save the new post I get the error described in the question.

but. If my entry points access any data (for example /posts, or /posts/:id/edit) then everything is working as expected.

I changed the question subject

Comment: Maybe a jsfiddle or jsbin for us?

Comment: i created a github project to show the issue - 
https://github.com/bsphere/ember-data-test